# Delete Customer Record From Whole Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Scenario - a customer may decide they no longer want any of their data in our database anymore, or our integration team request for specific customer records to be removed in order to insert fresh/ up to date data (say around 1 million customers).**

I'm attempting to find a solution for removing a customer's record from our database, this is to be run on demand manually for any given customer(s).

We have a Stored Procedure which seems to do the trick, however on production environments it can cause performance issues - there must be a better way to carry out this task.

We currently scan through all tables which holds customer data in (for example, we select all user tables which contain the column "CustomerID" and leave the rest). This adds up to around 300 tables all in all.

Once is has this list, it loops through all the tables via a cursor (which we probably need to get away from) and deletes the record with a statement like "WHERE CustomerID = @Customer ID" - so it would need to do this around 300 times (once per table).

Sometimes it's quick, sometimes it causes deadlocks and causes other processes to perform badly.

Viewing the actual execution plan causes massive issues as well, as it tries to display the 300 transactions.

This is pretty much what the Stored Procedure does currently

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveCustomerData]
    @CustomerNo VARCHAR(20) = 'TestDelete'

AS

DECLARE
    @TableName VARCHAR (50),
    @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50),
    @SchemaName VARCHAR(50),
    @ColumnName VARCHAR(50),
    @ObjectName VARCHAR(50),
    @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CustomerID INT;

SELECT
    @CustomerID = CustomerID
FROM
    Customers
WHERE
    CustomerNo = @CustomerNo;

DECLARE
    @Tables TABLE (
                    DatabaseName sysname,
                    SchemaName sysname,
                    TableName sysname,
                    ColumnName sysname
                    )
SET
    @SQL = 'SELECT
                ''' + DB_NAME() + ''' AS DatabaseName,
                schemas.name AS SchemaName,
                tables.name AS TableName,
                columns.name AS ColumnName
            FROM
                ' + DB_NAME() + '.sys.tables 
                JOIN ' + DB_NAME() + '.sys.schemas ON schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id JOIN ' + DB_NAME() + '.sys.columns ON columns.object_id = tables.object_id 
            WHERE
                columns.name IN (''CustomerID'')'

INSERT INTO @Tables
EXEC(@SQL)

--Clear data from tables    
DECLARE
    ClearDownCursor
CURSOR FOR  
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Tables
OPEN
    ClearDownCursor; 
FETCH NEXT FROM
    ClearDownCursor
INTO
    @DatabaseName,
    @SchemaName,
    @TableName,
    @ColumnName; 

SET @ObjectName =  @DatabaseName + '.' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName

--Deletes from table
SET @SQL = 'DELETE FROM ' + @ObjectName + ' WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL,  N'@CustomerID INT', 
        @CustomerID = @CustomerID;

FETCH NEXT FROM
    ClearDownCursor
INTO
    @DatabaseName,
    @SchemaName,
    @TableName,
    @ColumnName; 

CLOSE ClearDownCursor;
DEALLOCATE ClearDownCursor;
```

Comment: You can't handle GDPR/Right-to-forget with a simple blind stored procedure that doesn't even know what the database schema is

Comment: Do you actually need to get rid of the data in all the tables or just the personally identifiable information?

Comment: Never mind that `CustomerID` may mean different things for different tables, who said you *can* delete every such record? Financial data needs to be preserved for a certain number of years, and GDPR makes allowances for that. Foreign key constraints won't allow you to delete arbitrary records anyway.

Comment: To add to what @IAmDave asked, deleting PII isn't enough - it should never be stored in the first place without consent. Even with consent you need a way to remove it en masse when its validity period expires, which *won't* be the same for all types - eg contact vs financial.

Comment: The fact that you need to scan through the tables suggests you don't know where a customer may be located, or what tables are related to their data as well; which is a problem unto itself. As @PanagiotisKanavos has mentioned as well, the right to be forgotten doesn't directly translate into "delete the data"; there are times when actually you can't fulfil the request due to regulatory or legal obligations (for example, the name of the driver of a car insurance policy that was active until last month). Also making the person no longer identifiable at all is form of "forgetting".

Comment: Hi all - thank you for your comments, I used the above scenario as an example so that I didn't need to actually go into the details of our industry/ environment.

It's an environment where data is fed in incrementally and often needs to be cleared/ replayed so it's not something we can hard code (nor would we particularly want to, as more tables can be added with new releases).

So we would get the Customer data in a set of tables plus a load of records relating to the customer in other tables. It's sometimes necessary to clear completely for feeds to re-send in new information

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the comments - I don't feel comfortable going into the details of the industry I work in - the example above is just a related scenario. It's just a 'Customer' could have data in just one table or in 100, so we are hoping for a way to find all tables they are located in and delete from them

Comment: @iamdave - thanks for the comment. Yes, the data needs to be removed. Sometimes we have requests to clear down a 'Customer' or several, so that feeds can be replayed in (either for testing purposes or because the existing data is invalid somehow)